# C++11 write-after-read data race with memcpy

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I'm using thread sanitizer (TSAN) to detect data races in my multiprocess and multithreaded program. I'm using C++11, gcc 5.3.0, MPI (MPICH 3.2) for interprocess communication, and std::thread for concurrency. I'm running on Linux (Linux ronni 3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

TSAN is detecting a data race on a buffer which is written by one thread and read by many threads. In fact, the one writer thread is both communicating a buffer to other threads within its process, and also to other processes via MPI.

Here's the pseudocode:

```
void* shared_buffer;

WRITER THREAD:
// W0. write to shared_buffer

// W1. signal to readers that it's ok to read shared_buffer

// W2. give buffer to MPI, which uses it to send to other processes. At some point, the MPI runtime does a memcpy from shared_buffer into another buffer that it uses for its interprocess communication.

// W3. barrier


READER THREADS:
// R1. wait until it's ok to read shared_buffer

// R2. read shared_buffer

// R3. barrier
```

TSAN is detecting a write after read data race between R2 and the memcpy that is called in the MPI runtime, even though the shared_buffer should only be strictly read by memcpy, not written. When I switch the order of W1 and W2, the TSAN error goes away.

However, I'd prefer to keep this order as an optimization. My program runs fine (no crashes or nondeterminism) and I'm getting the "right answer".

So, I'm wondering if this TSAN warning is a false positive, or something I should be worried about. I generally prefer to keep my code "TSAN-clean". Could memcpy actually be modifying its source argument during the course of the memcpy?

Here's the specific line of memcpy that is getting flagged:

```
  Write of size 8 at 0x7d7c0000a800 by thread T2 (mutexes: write M98):
    #0 memcpy /scratch/m/gcc/src/gcc-5.3.0/libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:638 (libtsan.so.0+0x000000025b5a)
    #1 MPIDI_CH3U_Receive_data_found src/mpid/ch3/src/ch3u_handle_recv_pkt.c:152 (libmpi.so.12+0x0000002073ff)
```

Comment: "no nondeterminism". No, you just got lucky. TSAN is telling you that it's not deterministic.

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't ever write to the buffer in any thread. That makes it pretty useless for helping to find the error.

Comment: @MooingDuck you are right. I added that in.